# Datatables excel export stripHtml doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, datatables, export-to-excel

I have added a datatables export button to my datatable. In this table, some columns include html tags like

```
<button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-xs">BUTTON NAME</button>
```

When I first added the export button, it worked fine and the rows with HTML tags exported without their tags like: BUTTON NAME. But then I had to include a replace function to my button code as following:

```
buttons: [
  {
    extend: "excelHtml5",

    exportOptions: {
      format: {
        body: function (data, row, column, node) {
          return column === 18 ? data.replace(",", ".") : data;
        },
      },
    },

    tag: "img",

    className: "btn-excel",

    title: "file_title",

    titleAttr: "Excel",

    attr: {
      src: "../images/menu_img/excel.ico",
    },

    action: newexportaction,
  },
];
```

When I add this exportOptions attribute, the rows with HTML tags started to appear with their tags in the exported excel files. The column I am trying to replace doesn't have any html tag, they are all in some other column but this change affects them somehow.

I tried to add 'stripHtml: false' but it didn't make a difference. I also tried to write the replace function with switch case statements but it didn't work as well.

Comment: _"I tried to add 'stripHtml: false' but it didn't make a difference."_ - well if anything, you should add it with `true`. Documentation says true was the default already - but I can't tell if `extend: "excelHtml5"` is not perhaps overwriting that here somehow.

Comment: Hi, I tried that too but no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `format` function for your Excel export button, DataTables populates its `data` parameter with the **raw data** from each DataTable cell. So, that raw data is the full HTML content for your `BUTTON NAME` button.

More precisely, you get each cell's [`innerHtml`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/buttons.exportData()). See also [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML).

That is why some other options such as `stripHtml: true` no longer have any effect.

You can perform the equivalent `stripHtml` step (in your specific case) by using the `node` parameter instead of the `data` parameter - and accessing the node's [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) using JavaScript:

```js
body: function (data, row, column, node) {
  if (column === 5) {
    return data.replace(",", ".");
  } else if ( column === 3) {
    return node.innerText;
  } else {
    return data;
  }
}
```

My output in Excel is:

[image]

---

Here is my full test example, so you can see the source data:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/css/buttons.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.4/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/dataTables.buttons.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.6/js/buttons.html5.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office in Country</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td><button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-xs">BUTTON NAME</button></td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td><button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle btn-xs">BUTTON NAME</button></td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#example').DataTable( {
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'excelHtml5',
        exportOptions: {
          stripHtml: true,
          format: {
            body: function (data, row, column, node) {
              if (column === 5) {
                return data.replace(",", ".");
              } else if ( column === 3) {
                return node.innerText;
              } else {
                return data;
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]

  } );

} );

</script>

</body>
</html>
```